# How to pass array to function without variable instantiation, in C++

Tags: c++

Can I do this in C++ (if yes, what is the syntax?):

```
void func(string* strs) {
    // do something
}
func({"abc", "cde"});
```

I want to pass an array to a function, without instantiating it as a variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can't be done in the current C++, as defined by C++03.

The feature you are looking for is called "compound literals". It is present in C language, as defined by C99 (with C-specific capabilities, of course), but not in C++.

A similar feature is planned for C++ as well, but it is not there yet.

Comment: What about C++11?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in C++98, but you can with [initializer_lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357452/stdinitializer-list-as-function-argument) in C++1x.

Comment: I love initializer_lists so much.

Comment: Your linked example uses `std::vector`. How can you do the same for  arrays?

Answer (score 0):

As written, you can't do this.  The function expects a pointer-to-string.  Even if you were able to pass an array as a literal, the function call would generate errors because literals are considered constant (thus, the array of literals would be of type `const string*`, not `string*` as the function expects).

Comment: If I don't instantiate a variable, it still has a pointer (address).

Answer (score 0):

Use a variadic function to pass in unlimited untyped information into a function.  Then do whatever you want with the passed in data, such as stuffing it into an internal array.

[variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)