# initializer list as argument to operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, curly-braces, initializer-list

This question is related to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357452/stdinitializer-list-as-function-argument).

I try to use an initializer list to create an argument to be passed to `operator[]`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct A {

std::string& operator[](std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
  return vec.front();
}

};

int main()
{
    // ok
    std::vector<std::string> vec {"hello", "world", "test"};

    A a;
    // error: could not convert '{"hello", "world", "test"}' to 'std::vector...'
    a[ {"hello", "world", "test"} ];
}
```

My Compiler (GCC 4.6.1) complains:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
test.cpp:20:8: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘{’ token
test.cpp:20:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
test.cpp:20:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
test.cpp:20:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘]’ token
```

Should this be valid C++11?

Interestingly, when using `operator()` instead of `operator[]` it works.

Comment: Most definitely, it is compiler bug, as there should be absolutely no difference between `a.f({"aa", ""bb"})` and `a[{"aa", ""bb"}]`.

Comment: Passing a temporary explicitly compiles, though: `a[ std::vector<std::string>({"hello", "world", "test"}) ];`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is valid C++11 and should work in any compliant compiler.

Please note that C++11 support in gcc is quite immature, and this code example will not compile in any 4.6 version, but only in 4.7 svn snapshot versions.

Comment: Using GCC 4.7 from svn trunk revision 179769 doesn't work either. Same error report as with GCC 4.6.

Comment: @MichelSteuwer: Right before posting this I tried with my local build of gcc 4.7 which is r182904 (I think), and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid. The version of GCC you're using doesn't have full support for C++11 yet, so it fails to compile, even when it's standard-compliant.

A more recent version of GCC compiles your code.
See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nGYdvrTb9).