# Evaluation order of elements in an initializer list

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-precedence

Why is function `g()` called first? I defined `g()` as the second element in the initializer list.

Is the following quote from the standard, relating to initializer-lists, relevant?

> §8.5.4.4: Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (§14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int f() { std::cout << "f"; return 0;}
int g() { std::cout << "g"; return 0;}

void h(std::vector<int> v) {}

int main() {

   h({f(), g()});
}
```

**Output:**

```
gf
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any initializer lists.

Comment: Evaluation order of function parameters is unspecified in C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c

Comment: Note to all commenting and duplicate voters: The OP isn't calling a function with two arguments, the OP is calling a function with *one* argument, a vector which is initialized using uniform initialization and the `std::initializer_list` constructor of the vector.

Comment: @KerrekSB consider edited post

Comment: @user5905343 Can you please tell us what compiler you are using? And what version of it?

Comment: I'm removing the duplicate (never mind, got beaten to it) because the OP changed the question to match the original title, which I'm also restoring. However, @OP, neither GCC, nor Clang, give me that output with your revised post. Could you post more information about where you obtained this result?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me. Which compiler are you using, what are the compiler args? I am going to give OP 5-10 minutes to respond, and then I will VTC as unclear.

Comment: Did you run the code in the edited post, or is this the result from the previous version?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg why they vote down when they dont understand question

Comment: @user5905343, what you are saying seems extremely unlikely. I am giving you the benefit of the doubt, but not for long.

Comment: MSVC 19 results in `fg` as well (tested on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual)

Comment: @user5905343 Your original question had code different from what was being asked. The edited question is unreproducible on 3 popular compilers and you are not providing info on compiler you have used, so commenters are skeptical about the correctness.

Comment: @SergeyA consider there is just one argument in function call

Comment: @user5905343, yes, there is one argument, no one is disputing that. I asked you specific question, can you answer it?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic    I'm compiling With Gcc on Eclipse and i have no Error

Comment: Does "I have no error" mean that you actually get `fg` as result?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic , I mean i don't have compile Error but i expect according  standard to get " fg " but i have " gf " on output

Comment: Which exact version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic    gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4

Comment: could be this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253

Comment: @KerrekSB Why is it not an init-list? AFAIK an init-list initializes an object. And isn't this what's happening here with the init-list `{f(), g()}` initializing the vector? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nik-Lz: The question has since been edited, the comment no longer applies.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah alright. Thanks. But just to note that this `{f(), g()}` is an initializer list.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: Yes, thanks, I realize that. The comment served no other purpose than to get the OP to fix the question at a time where the question was unclear.

Comment: Re: "are evaluated in the order in which they appear": do you know the rationale for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It seems to me that</del> the quote is relevant (the compiler sees an initializer list):

> 8.5/14,16:
>
> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> T x = a;
>
> **as well as in argument passing**, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) is called copy-initialization.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> The semantics of initializers are as follows[...]: If the initializer is a braced-init-list, the object is list-initialized (8.5.4).

(more details in [std::initializer_list as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357452/3235496) and [Folds (ish) In C++11](http://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/05/14/folds_in_cpp11_ish.html))

Moreover any `{}`-list should be sequenced (the standard uses a very strong wording about this fact. See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1030).

So it's [probably a GCC bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36852367/3235496) (fixed after gcc v4.9.0).

Indeed, trying various GCC version, I get:

```
GCC      with --std=c++11   without (--std=c++98)
4.7.3        fg                    gf  <-
4.8.1        fg                    gf  <-
4.8.2        fg                    gf  <-
4.9.0        fg                    gf  <-
4.9.2        fg                    fg
5.1.0        fg                    fg
5.2.0        fg                    fg
6.1.0        fg                    fg
```

Extended initializer lists are only available with C++11 but GCC compiles the code anyway (with a warning, e.g. see [`gcc -Wall -Wextra`](https://godbolt.org/g/8Hll7t) vs [`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11`](https://godbolt.org/g/5DL8Gf)).

Comment: i tried both  in any case result is the same problrm isnt adding  --std=c++11

Comment: @user5905343 unfortunately gcc v4.8.4 is missing on https://gcc.godbolt.org but considering the above tests it seems a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a *braced-init-list*, so that rule does not apply.

> `[C++14: 5.17/9]:` A *braced-init-list* may appear on the right-hand side of
>
> - an assignment to a scalar, in which case the initializer list shall have at most a single element. The meaning of `x={v}`, where `T` is the scalar type of the expression `x`, is that of `x=T{v}`. The meaning of `x={}` is `x=T{}`.
> - an assignment to an object of class type, in which case the initializer list is passed as the argument to the assignment operator function selected by overload resolution (13.5.3, 13.3).

Comment: Probably I'm wrong but a *braced-init-list* may appear in many other contexts: e.g. *for-range-initializer* (`for (for-range-declaration: braced-init-list) statement`, §6.5.4), *jump-statements* (`return braced-init-list;`, §6.6), ...

Comment: @manlio: Meh, okay well I did try to find the proof that _this_ case doesn't have a _braced-init-list_ in it (which would be a much better answer) but concluded I'd have to quote too much.

Comment: Also considering [std::initializer_list as function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2357452/3235496) and especially the [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2357688/3235496), argument passing is supposed to have the same meaning as `=` initializer (both is copy initialization). So isn't this copy initialization (object *list-initialized* via *braced-init-list*)?

Comment: @manlio: Haven't got a moment to investigate right now. Feel free to write an answer :)